# how to determin the North west radiant score(270-360 degree) to decide score

Tags: matlab, tiff, disk

I have a code in matlab as below. the code is very confusing. Now i need to decide the north west part of the disk (270-360) degree if the fuel type are f3 and f5, then it is a shia. i need to return yes or no for shia.

```
% base path
fireline_path = 'Documents/fireline/';

% EOSD landcover file
landcover_file = fullfile(fireline_path,'landcover/EOSD/083O_lc_1/083O_lc_1.TIF');
[landcover,cmap_landcover,R_landcover0] = geotiffread(landcover_file);
proj_landcover = geotiffinfo(landcover_file);
pixelsize = 25; % 25m UTM grid

% trim raster to area around town of Lake
i_trim = 3001:3500;
j_trim = 3001:3500;
landcover = landcover(i_trim,j_trim);
[x11,y11] = pix2map(R_landcover0,i_trim(1),j_trim(1));
R_landcover = makerefmat(x11,y11,pixelsize,-pixelsize);

% read in damaged propeties and get their locations in grid
damage_shapefile = fullfile(fireline_path,'work/slavelake/damaged_properties_SL.shp');
damage = shaperead(damage_shapefile);
x_damage = [damage(~strcmp({damage.Damage},'Undamaged')).X];
y_damage = [damage(~strcmp({damage.Damage},'Undamaged')).Y];
[i_damage, j_damage] = map2pix(R_landcover,x_damage,y_damage);
ind_damage = sub2ind(size(landcover),round(i_damage),round(j_damage));

% create landcover -> fuel mappings
fuelmappings = zeros(max(landcover(:)),1);
ind_vegclass = [52,81,82,83,100,211,221,231]; % indicies of classes present that are vegetation
veg_loadings = [...
    3,...'Shrub Low'
    3,...'Wetland-treed'
    3,...'Wetland-shrub'
    1,...'Wetland-herb'
    1,...'Herbs'
    5,...'Coniferous-dense'
    5,...'Broadleaf-dense'
    5]; %Mixedwood-dense'
fuelmappings(ind_vegclass) = veg_loadings;
landcover(landcover==0) = 1; % set nodata cells to 1, this will map to no fuel
fuelmap = fuelmappings(landcover);

% create binary fuel map (F3 or F5)
fuelmapbw = fuelmap>=3;


%%
% flag pixels within 1/2 mile of dense areas
shiasum = zeros(size(landcover)); % initialize summary
disp('Percent of damaged/destroyed properties in SHIA:')
densitythresholds = .25;%[.75, .67, .5, .33, .25];
for densitythreshold = densitythresholds

    % create filter to calculate shia (create a disk and then zero out unwanted
    % pixels)
    shiadistmiles = .5; %miles
    shiadistmeters = shiadistmiles*unitsratio('meters','miles');
    shiadistpix = shiadistmeters/pixelsize;
    hshia = fspecial('disk',shiadistpix);
    hshia(1:floor(shiadistpix),:) = 0;
    xy = -floor(shiadistpix):floor(shiadistpix);
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(xy,fliplr(xy));
    f70 = -tan(deg2rad(70))*X;
    hshia(Y<f70) = 0;
    f20 = -tan(deg2rad(20))*X;
    hshia(Y>f20) = 0;
    hshia(hshia>0) = 1;
    hshia = hshia/sum(hshia(:));

    close all
    shiavals = filter2(hshia,fuelmapbw);
    shia = filter2(hshia,fuelmapbw) > densitythreshold;

    linkimage(fuelmapbw,shia)
    hold on
    plot(j_damage,i_damage,'x')
    hold off

    propsinshia = sum(shia(ind_damage))/numel(ind_damage);

    disp(['With threshold of ' num2str(densitythreshold) ':'])
    disp(propsinshia * 100)

    outfile = [fireline_path 'shia/SlaveLake_'...
        num2str(densitythreshold*100,'%02d') '.tif'];
    geotiffwrite(outfile,shia,R_landcover,...
        'CoordRefSysCode',proj_landcover.GeoTIFFCodes.PCS)

    shiasum = shiasum+shia;
end


lookup = [0 fliplr(densitythresholds) * 100];
shia = lookup(shiasum+1);
outfile = [fireline_path 'shia/SlaveLake_v2.tif'];
geotiffwrite(outfile,uint8(shia),R_landcover,...
        'CoordRefSysCode',proj_landcover.GeoTIFFCodes.PCS)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I do not how to modify the code into determine the north west part of the disk fuel time to decide the shia (yes or no)